# Images in emails are not displaying on iOS when sent through python

Tags: python, ios, email, html-email, email-attachments

We are trying to set up an automated mailer using python. When it sends out the email, it displays images for our users on Gmail and other android mail clients, but does not seem to show the images for iOS' mail client.

We are unsure how to fix this. We have tried iframes, base 64, as well as sending images as attachments and it did not seem to work.

We are currently using smtplib and send MIME messages

```
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
...
part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
message.attach(part1)
message.attach(part2)
...
...

<a href="#"><img src="https://test.png" ></img></a><a href="#">
...
```

This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like]

This is what it looks like:

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: Images are self closing, so remove `</img>`. Also, make sure you have a width attrbitue on the image, i.e. `<img src="..." width="...">`. In terms of the different size text, make sure you use inline code, not embedded CSS. Let us know how you go - if not much improvement, please post your full HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out Apple Mail doesn't support vh, so we just changed the image height and width to be formatted by pixels instead and it worked. Thanks for the help!